# Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.github.difflib.text.DiffRowGenerator$$Lambda$0

Tags: java, android, gradle

Inside my Android project I'm using [java-diff-utils](https://github.com/java-diff-utils/java-diff-utils).

I've added it to dependency this way:

```
implementation group: 'com.github.wumpz', name: 'diffutils', version: '2.2'
```

Also tried change it to this:

```
implementation 'io.github.java-diff-utils:java-diff-utils:4.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

I have two test devices: a tablet with **Android 6.0.1** and a phone with **Android 8.1.0.**

When I'm running this project on phone, everything goes fine. But on tablet, as soon as a hit the java-diff-utils code, app crashes with error

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.github.difflib.text.DiffRowGenerator$$Lambda$0
    at com.github.difflib.text.DiffRowGenerator.<clinit>(DiffRowGenerator.java:52)
    at com.github.difflib.text.DiffRowGenerator.create(DiffRowGenerator.java:210)
    at Fragments.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:38)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The same issue happened, when I was using Sugar ORM.

My build.gradle config:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "someid"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
```

Why this is happening and is there any way I can solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is usage of `java.util.function.BiPredicate` in `DiffRowGenerator.java:52` of library you using (that is where crash happen due to stacktrace). Link to [source](https://github.com/java-diff-utils/java-diff-utils/blob/diffutils-2.2/src/main/java/com/github/difflib/text/DiffRowGenerator.java#L52). Whole package `java.util.function.*` can be used only starting API 24 (Android 7.0). Thats why it's working on Android 8 and not working on Android 6. More about java 8 compatibility with android you can read in official documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

If you have to use that library you have options:

- Do not support Android below 7.0.
- Use older library version. As I can see that library started using Java 8 features since version 2.0. So you can try version 1.2 of that library.
- Fork library and rewrite all places where unsupported Java 8 functionality is used.

Comment: Thanks. But when I'm targeting everything except 2.2, I'm getting "Failed to resolve" error.

Comment: It's easy to explain. According to mvnrepository, only versions 2.2 and 3.0 are published. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.wumpz/diffutils You can add dependency by cloning repository and building lib by yourself at required version.

Comment: Well, thats sad. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can contact library author at github and ask him to publish other versions.

Comment: @Alex Hi. I am the maintainer / author of this library. Which version do you need? By the way it has a new home and organization: https://github.com/java-diff-utils/java-diff-utils.

Comment: @wumpz Hi, actually I need a version that can work on java 7. Thanks.

Comment: Wow. Nearly a year later. Just check the commits when I switched to Java 8. I think at the beginning. So a rewind to Java 7 would be very problematic. However if you provide a PR or help in other ways I could imagine to do a Java 7 branch.

Comment: Additionally you should file an issue at GitHub for this.